# Get results from Firebase dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am able to retrieve results from a Firebase query but I am having trouble retrieving them as a dictionary to populate a tableView. Here's how I'm storing the query results:

```
var invites: Array<FIRDataSnapshot> = []
func getAlerts(){

        let invitesRef = self.rootRef.child("invites")
        let query = invitesRef.queryOrderedByChild("invitee").queryEqualToValue(currentUser?.uid)
        query.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

            self.invites.append(snapshot)
            print(self.invites)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

Printing self.invites returns the following:

```
[Snap (invites) {
    "-KKQWErkyuehmbxom8NO" =     {
        invitedBy = T2k7Bm9G9RNLcHLvLlKApRbnas23;
        invitee = dRJ1FqctSfTlLF8iO2ddlc9BANJ3;
        role = guardian;
    };
}]
```

I'm having trouble populating the tableView. The cell labels don't show anything:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let inviteDict = invites[indexPath.row].value as! [String : AnyObject]
    let role = inviteDict["role"] as? String

    cell.textLabel!.text = role

    return cell
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: Printed the dictionary to console after my function is run, and it's printing `[]`. Why is it losing it's values?

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        getAlerts() // inside of function prints values
        print(self.invites) //prints []
    }
```

EDIT 2: Paul's solution worked!! I added the following function to have Firebase "listen" for results! I may have to edit this to only show alerts for the logged in user, but this has at least pointed me in the right direction:

```
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        getAlerts()

        configureDatabase()
    }

    func configureDatabase() {

        // Listen for new messages in the Firebase database
        let ref = self.rootRef.child("invites").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            self.invites.append(snapshot)
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: self.invites.count-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        })
    }
```

Comment: You Should check that the dictionary isn't returning nil after your query outside of your getAlerts function. I've been having the same problem. The value is stored inside the function, but once I leave it the value returns nil

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think you're on to something! I just updated my question. I printed the dict to console after the console is run and now it's printing `[]`. What the heck is going on? How can I fix this?

Comment: I've been trying to solve this problem myself for about two days now. I will be paying very close attention to this thread. Hopefully someone will come up with a solution. In the meantime you can try using a property observer. It will tell you where your dictionary is being set to nil. I learned about it today myself.

Comment: @TaylorSimpson check out the solution! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [friendlychat Firebase codelab](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/) for an example of populating a table view from an asynchronous call. Specifically, see viewDidLoad and configureDatabase in [FCViewController.swift](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/blob/master/ios/swift/FriendlyChatSwift/FCViewController.swift).

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I updated my question with the solution that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your array will always return [ ] because Firebase is async. If you add `var invites: Array<FIRDataSnapshot> = []` inside of the Firebase closure you will print the data you are looking for, but im assumming you would like to use the variable outside of the closure. in order to complete that you must create a completion within `getAlerts()` function. If you are not sure how to complete that do a google search and that will solve your question.